# What a good approach will be to solve this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

- I know that this function from A to A is 1-1 and also onto.

How many functions like this exists ?
The set A contain 12 elements.

$$\forall a \in A $$
$$f(f(a)) \ne a{\rm{  ,    }}$$
$$f(f(f(a))) = a{\rm{       }}$$

I dont know how to start solving this problem.
Should I use inclusion and exclusion to solve this ?

Comment: suggest letting $A$ have exactly three elements, write out carefully

Answer (score 5):

You want to count certain permutations of a finite set $A$ with $n$ elements.

This problem boils down to learning about [cycle notation of permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation).

What you want is permutations that consist of three-cycles and no fixed points.

So we can immediately see no such functions exist if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

If $n$ is a multiple of $3$ there are $\frac{n!}{(n/3)!3^{n/3}}$ such permutations.

Why?

The permutation will look like this:

$(***)(***)(***)\dots (***)$

we have to select how to fill in the asterisks. There are $n!$ ways to do so, however the order in which the cycles appear is irrelevant, also notice that every $3$-cycle can be rotated internally in three ways and yields the same permutation. (For example, $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,1)$ and $(3,1,2)$ are the same permutation). Therefore the $n!$ possible arrangements fit into groups of size $(\frac{n}{3})!3^{n/3}$ that all yield the same permutation.

Final answer:

$$\frac{n!}{(n/3)!3^{n/3}}$$

if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: Nice answer.  (I made some very minor changes, but please change them back if any are in error.)

Comment: The changes are good, thank you.

Comment: @dREaM what should I read to understand and to get to solution for this kind of problems ? 
for now I learned : set theory , combinatorics, graph theory .
what should I learn ? I really want to solve this kind of problems.
I'm very depressed for not knowing how to solve it.
can I get a little guidance for what to read next ? in addition to cycle notation of permutations

Comment: Maybe some abstract algebra and continuing with the combinatorics. I learned about cycle decomposición with dummit and foote.

Comment: @dREaM thanks a lot. really helpful

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Any invertible $f:A \to A$ corresponds a permutation of the elements.

That permutation may be [decomposed into cycles](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Understanding_the_cycle_decomposition).  Note that $f$ is a satisfactory map if and only if all of the cycles in the resulting decomposition have length $3$.

Comment: for a circle you mean for example a-b-c and then back to a ?

Comment: Right.  So, for example: if we define $f$ by
$$
1 \to 2\\
2 \to 3\\
3 \to 1\\
4 \to 5\\
5 \to 6\\
6 \to 4
$$
then the permutation associated with $f$ contains two cycles of length $3$, namely: $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The existence will depend on the size of $A$. For example if $|A|=1 \text{ or } 2$, then no such function can exist (because by the first condition the identity function is already ruled out). For $3 \leq |A| < \infty$. We can do the counting as follows. Let $A=\{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$. Then any bijective function from $A$ to itself can be represented as a product of disjoint cycles. So the problem reduces to finding all elements which can be represented as cycles of length $3$ (and no fixed elements) in $S_n$. If you are not familiar with symmetric group $S_n$ then let me know and I will modify my hint accordingly.

Comment: @dREaM yes you are right I have fixed that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with symmetric group.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to answer the question "how many such functions exist", but it appears that at least one such function exists:

For suitable A, let $$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$$ 
Then, $$ff(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
And so $$fff(x)=x$$

Comment: If the set is infinite it is easy to prove there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @dREaM I assumed the OP was looking for how many different types of functions had this property